# Hibernate generate pk ID using naming strategy

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm using Hibernate JPA. I'd like to extend a base class containing my pk generator and some hash equals code, however my company is using table_name_id to describe ID's in the physical database making this seemingly impossible. I was just told I could use hibernates naming strategy to dynamically prefix the table name to my variable, however I haven't found a good example illustrating how to accomplish this. Would someone be able to point me to some example code or documentation on how to achieve this.

superclass

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Base implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = AUTO)
    @Column(name="ID", nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    ....
}
```

Subclass A

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TABLE_A")
public class TableA extends Base {
// physical model needs base pk id to be prefixed with table_a resulting in table_a_id.
...
}
```

Subclass B

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TABLE_B")
public class TableB extends Base {
// physical model needs base pk id to be prefixed with table_b resulting in table_b_id.
...
}
```

Comment: I may have read your question wrong but do you want: To prefix the id of your entity when you persist it?

Comment: @Andreas see code sample above. Hopefully this will better explain what I'm looking to do.

Comment: He want's his Id column to change to table_name_id instead of ID, the question is if there is a way to dynamicly pre-fix the id with the name of the table so he doesn't have to put all the id generation code in each subclass with column annotations to rename the column.

Comment: @George: http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t19838.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just do exactly the same thing which ensures that the generated column name for all PKs will have the format `tablename_id` .

By default when using hibernate in JPA mode  , it uses `EJB3NamingStrategy` as its default naming strategy.By creating the following custom `NamingStrategy` which extending `EJB3NamingStrategy` , you can change the naming strategy for the primary key only and keep other naming strategies specified by the JPA standard remain unchanged.

```
public class CustomNamingStrategy extends EJB3NamingStrategy {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1953826881322136108L;
    private String currentTableName;

    public String propertyToColumnName(String propertyName) {

        if (propertyName.equalsIgnoreCase("id")) {
            return currentTableName + "_id";
        } else {
            return StringHelper.unqualify(propertyName);
        }
    }

    public String tableName(String tableName) {
        currentTableName = tableName;
        return tableName;
    }
}
```

Please note that you have to remove `@Column(name="ID")` from all of your `@Entity` such that hibernate will use the custom `NamingStrategy` to generate the column name.